# Is ESLint a Vim plugin?

Tags: vim, eslint, neovim

Vim Awesome lists ESLint as a plugin: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/eslint. However, also on that page it says *"...your plugins (and ESLint) are ..."* implying ESLint is not a Vim plugin.

I am trying to work out how to apply ESLint to JavaScript files I am writing in Vim. I would like to do so (at least initially) without any plugins. I think it might help me to achieve this if I knew whether or not ESLint is a Vim plugin or not.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It is a general linter for javascript.  See https://eslint.org/

If you want to use ESLint in Vim, you can use a vim plugin (such as ALE or the eslint vim plugin) to help you.  Or you can use the command line interface eslint offers if you don't want to use plugins.